# Images that look good on display seriously degrade when printed

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have this JAVA swing desktop application where i am printing some reports.
The reports contain some text and some images.

These images, when displayed on the screen through my application, looks absolutely fine.

But when the same image image is sent for printing on a formatted document, the image part looks degraded in quality but the text remains perfect.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

P.S. The application is being used at more than 100 different centers. It is not a printer issue as all the printers can not be defected at the same time. I was thinking if any one could suggest me on how to set the dpi of the document to be printed so that i could get a higher resolution.

Comment: The application is being used at more than 100 different centers. It is not a printer issue as all the printers can not be defected at the same time. I was thinking if any one could suggest me on how to set the dpi of the document to be printed so that i could get a higher resolution.

Comment: I think the first question is: what are the resolutions of these images? A medium resolution image might look fine on screen, but if you blow it up to 8x11 it won't look very good.

Comment: A workstation monitor is usually 96 pixels an inch.  Printers print at 300 or 400 pixels an inch.  You need an image with 3 or 4 times the resolution of your display image for printing.